# Monitoring disconnects in QuickFIX/n

Tags: c#, quickfixn

Working with QuickFIX/n and need to find a way to monitor potential crashes on the executor side (I am developing the client side). I see there is logging when a connection stops but no way of tracking and triggering anything in the code.

I have looked at [Quickfix/n - No event for connection timeout or host not found?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44345389/quickfix-n-no-event-for-connection-timeout-or-host-not-found) but it only addresses initial connection, not crashes post connection. QuickFIX/J has SessionStateListener https://quickfixj.org/javadoc/1.6.4/quickfix/SessionStateListener.html but not finding anything similar in the C# variant.

Basically, need to find a way to create an observer but do not see anything built in that could be of use.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a definitive solution but ends justify the means for now.

Have created own implementation of the `ILogFactory` (rather than use builtins) and it listens to the message containing " disconnecting: " then sends info to applicable services. Causes some strange coupling but currently not seeing a clean way like the java implementation does it.